# Fill Ellipse with wave animation

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-silverlight

I have created an ellipse in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight App and UWP both
and I wanted to fill it with animating waves,
For this purpose, I am following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22044041/animate-circles-fill-using-sine-wave)

but it is for WPF so I am unable to use some control like "Visual Brush".

I wanted to fill ellipse with wave similar to this (ignore 50% in the image) -

[image]

And here is my eliipse

```
<Ellipse Name="WaveEllipse" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Stroke="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
         StrokeThickness="4"
         Width="225"
         Height="225">
</Ellipse>
```

any alternate on the visual brush?
mainly I wanted to implement it in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight, but I will switch to UWP if it is not available on WP platform

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Before giving you the code, have a look at this animated *gif* below to try to understand how this animation could be created.

[image]

Make sense, right? All we need to do is to create a shape like this, animate its offset X(endlessly) and Y(water level), and finally just clip it with an ellipse.

So first you will need to use *Adobe Illustrator* or similar tools to create this shape. In *AI*, there's a *Zig Zag* effect(see screenshot below) that's perfectly for this. You just need to make sure the starting point is at the same position as the ending one, so when you repeat the animation, it will feel like it's never ending.

[image]

What's currently missing in UWP is the ability to clip a `UIElement` with a non-rectangular shape, so here we have to export this as a *png* (otherwise we would export it as a *svg* and use `Path` to display it).

Also for the same reason, the clipping part requires a lot of work. Like in Jet Chopper's answer, that's tons of code to just get a `surfaceBrush`! Not to mention that you will also need to manually handle device lost and app lifecycle.

Thankfully, in Creators Update(i.e. *15063*), there's a new API called `LoadedImageSurface` that creates a `CompositionSurfaceBrush` by an image uri with a couple of lines' code. In my code example below, you will see that I use this, which means, if you want to support older versions of Windows 10, you will need to replace it with what's in Jet's answer.

### Code

The idea is to create a UserControl called `WaveProgressControl` which encapsulates all the animation logic and exposes a dependency property called **`Percent`** that controls the *water level*.

**The `WaveProgressControl` control - XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WaveProgressControlRepo.WaveProgressControl"
             Height="160"
             Width="160">

    <Grid x:Name="Root">
        <Ellipse x:Name="ClippedImageContainer"
                 Fill="White"
                 Margin="6" />
        <Ellipse x:Name="CircleBorder"
                 Stroke="#FF0289CD"
                 StrokeThickness="3" />
        <TextBlock Foreground="#FF0289CD"
                   FontSize="36"
                   FontWeight="SemiBold"
                   TextAlignment="Right"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Width="83"
                   Margin="0,0,12,0">
            <Run Text="{x:Bind Percent, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <Run Text="%"
                 FontSize="22" />
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**The `WaveProgressControl` control - Code-behind**

```
private readonly Compositor _compositor;
private readonly CompositionPropertySet _percentPropertySet;

public WaveProgressControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _compositor = Window.Current.Compositor;

    _percentPropertySet = _compositor.CreatePropertySet();
    _percentPropertySet.InsertScalar("Value", 0.0f);

    Loaded += OnLoaded;
}

public double Percent
{
    get => (double)GetValue(PercentProperty);
    set => SetValue(PercentProperty, value);
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty PercentProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Percent", typeof(double), typeof(WaveProgressControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(0.0d, (s, e) =>
        {
            var self = (WaveProgressControl)s;
            var propertySet = self._percentPropertySet;
            propertySet.InsertScalar("Value", Convert.ToSingle(e.NewValue) / 100);
        }));

private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CompositionSurfaceBrush imageSurfaceBrush;

    SetupClippedWaveImage();
    SetupEndlessWaveAnimationOnXAxis();
    SetupExpressionAnimationOnYAxisBasedOnPercentValue();

    void SetupClippedWaveImage()
    {
        // Note LoadedImageSurface is only available in 15063 onward.
        var imageSurface = LoadedImageSurface.StartLoadFromUri(new Uri(BaseUri, "/Assets/wave.png"));
        imageSurfaceBrush = _compositor.CreateSurfaceBrush(imageSurface);
        imageSurfaceBrush.Stretch = CompositionStretch.None;
        imageSurfaceBrush.Offset = new Vector2(120, 248);

        var maskBrush = _compositor.CreateMaskBrush();
        var maskSurfaceBrush = ClippedImageContainer.GetAlphaMask(); // CompositionSurfaceBrush
        maskBrush.Mask = maskSurfaceBrush;
        maskBrush.Source = imageSurfaceBrush;

        var imageVisual = _compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
        imageVisual.RelativeSizeAdjustment = Vector2.One;
        ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(ClippedImageContainer, imageVisual);

        imageVisual.Brush = maskBrush;
    }

    void SetupEndlessWaveAnimationOnXAxis()
    {
        var waveOffsetXAnimation = _compositor.CreateScalarKeyFrameAnimation();
        waveOffsetXAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(1.0f, -80.0f, _compositor.CreateLinearEasingFunction());
        waveOffsetXAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        waveOffsetXAnimation.IterationBehavior = AnimationIterationBehavior.Forever;
        imageSurfaceBrush.StartAnimation("Offset.X", waveOffsetXAnimation);
    }

    void SetupExpressionAnimationOnYAxisBasedOnPercentValue()
    {
        var waveOffsetYExpressionAnimation = _compositor.CreateExpressionAnimation("Lerp(248.0f, 120.0f, Percent.Value)");
        waveOffsetYExpressionAnimation.SetReferenceParameter("Percent", _percentPropertySet);
        imageSurfaceBrush.StartAnimation("Offset.Y", waveOffsetYExpressionAnimation);
    }
}
```

**The `MainPage`**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <local:WaveProgressControl x:Name="WaveProgressControl" />

    <Slider Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="24"
            Value="{x:Bind WaveProgressControl.Percent, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Grid>
```

I have put everything into this [sample project](https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/WaveProgressControlRepo) and below is a live demo. Enjoy! :)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the LoadedImageSurface. It's been so hard to load images.

Comment: Thanks you both answer in combined help me very much

Comment: Thx, Can I use it in business?

Comment: @lindexi absolutely!

Comment: @JustinXL Thx your code but I don't know why is `imageSurfaceBrush.Offset = new Vector2(120, 248);`, can you talk to me why use `120,248`?

Comment: @lindexi that's the initial offset of the image. Note the image is 400x400.

Comment: @JustinXL Thx for your reply, can I think it will offset of the image's center?

Comment: @lindexi, the image is placed at the center of the screen, then it's pushed down by `248` and right by `120`.

Answer (score 12):

Here's the UWP sample. You may adjust it as you wish:

```
<Canvas>
    <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse" Width="256" Height="256" Fill="DarkViolet" Stroke="DeepSkyBlue" StrokeThickness="8"/>
    <Border x:Name="VisualBorder" Opacity="0.5"/>
</Canvas>
```

And code behind:

```
    private async void CreateVisuals()
    {
        var compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this).Compositor;

        var bitmap = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice(),
            new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Wave-PNG-Transparent-Picture.png"));

        var drawingSurface =
            CanvasComposition.CreateCompositionGraphicsDevice(compositor, CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice())
                .CreateDrawingSurface(bitmap.Size,
                    DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized, DirectXAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
        using (var ds = CanvasComposition.CreateDrawingSession(drawingSurface))
        {
            ds.Clear(Colors.Transparent);
            ds.DrawImage(bitmap);
        }

        var surfaceBrush = compositor.CreateSurfaceBrush(drawingSurface);
        surfaceBrush.Stretch = CompositionStretch.None;

        var maskedBrush = compositor.CreateMaskBrush();
        maskedBrush.Mask = Ellipse.GetAlphaMask();
        maskedBrush.Source = surfaceBrush;

        var sprite = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
        sprite.Size = new Vector2((float)Ellipse.Width, (float)Ellipse.Height);
        sprite.Brush = maskedBrush;
        sprite.CenterPoint = new Vector3(sprite.Size / 2, 0);
        sprite.Scale = new Vector3(0.9f);

        ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(VisualBorder, sprite);

        var offsetAnimation = compositor.CreateScalarKeyFrameAnimation();
        offsetAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(0, 0);
        offsetAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(1, 256, compositor.CreateLinearEasingFunction());
        offsetAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        offsetAnimation.IterationBehavior = AnimationIterationBehavior.Forever;

        surfaceBrush.StartAnimation("Offset.X", offsetAnimation);
    }
}
```

Here's how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thank's, will it work for windows phone 8.1 silverlight , i am checking now .....

Comment: something is missed in code ??

Thanks for your effort but it is not as i want it fully filled with "DarkViolet" 
i want fill upto that wave and fill according to progress as i mention in the given solution link.
And it is targeted for Anniversary 14393 SDK  some api is not available in 10240 sdk , still some users mobile is not upgraded to anniversary update , so i don't want to target 14393 upgrade directly.
But still thanks for your efforts. 
............................ :)

Comment: Minimum SDK is 10586. You can move Offset.Y to make it fill the whole ellipse. And change a wave so it could hide content below the wave

Comment: Thanks you both answer in combined help me very much

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved this using a simple solution:

Wave2.png is a extended ( copy pasted the image and added to the end of the first image ) to make it longer.

The solution works on WP8/Store apps/UWP/Silverlight

[image]

```
<Border
        Background="White"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        CornerRadius="10000"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        BorderThickness="5">
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse
                x:Name="ellipse"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Height="200"
                Width="200">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush
                        x:Name="WaveImage"
                        Stretch="None"
                        ImageSource="wave2.png">
                        <ImageBrush.Transform>
                            <CompositeTransform
                                TranslateY="200"
                                TranslateX="299" />
                        </ImageBrush.Transform>
                    </ImageBrush>
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
            <TextBlock
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Text="HUJ" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
```

And here is the animation code:

```
<Storyboard
        x:Name="AnimateWave">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
            RepeatBehavior="Forever"
            EnableDependentAnimation="True"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(Brush.Transform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"
            Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame
                KeyTime="0:0:5"
                Value="-299" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

Comment: Awesome idea 

Comment: @ShubhamSahu just checked if can be done without image extension. Yup, just change the X translations from 299 and -299 to 99 and -99.

And accordingly adjust the Y translations