# Uwp advanced animations

Tags: c#, animation, uwp

I want to create advanced animation with C# UWP.

Animation that would look like this:

[image]

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Since you mentioned C# - you want to make it with code behind?

Comment: Honestly, you might have to just use a video or a special pixel shader. I don't think this can be done with out-of-the-box WPF animations.

Comment: Looks like moving shapes or video under blurred `CompositionBackdropBrush`

Comment: Square peg round hole.  Use a animation application to create a video or an HTML canvas animation.  If it's a background and requires no transparency, go with video.

Comment: You can do it with composition API, but i was to stupid to understand that. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure what is under your blur effect. Looks like it is a wave related animation. So let's make your animation to two parts:

1. See Justin's answer on the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46021277/fill-ellipse-with-wave-animation/46057193#46057193), the answer will tell you how you can create a wave animation.
2. As mentioned above by Jet Chopper, we can add blur brush(CompositionBackdropBrush) based on sample code from this [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.xamlcompositionbrushbase)

So to understand this in a simple way, you can:

1. Download Justin's sample from [here](https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/WaveProgressControlRepo)
2. Add BackdropBlurBrush to his project
3. Write the following code in MainPage XAML:

> ```
>   <local:WaveProgressControl x:Name="WaveProgressControl" />
> ```

```
    <Rectangle Width="200" Height="200" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="3" >
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <blureffect:BackdropBlurBrush BlurAmount="10"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
```

The blureffect above refer to the namespace which include your BackdropBlurBrush. In this way you have a basic sample that looks like what you want. You can modify your project based on this.